# BizTalk 2010 with Oracle (no SQL Server)

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I've seen a lot of talk about Oracle adapters for BizTalk 2010.

Is it possible to have BizTalk 2010 without a SQL Server install, or is it too tightly coupled ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BizTalk only works with SQL server to host it's databases. Check out the requirements.

http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/system-requirements.aspx

The Oracle adapters are for integrating to Oracle databases or the "[Oracle eBusiness Suite](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9658811)". Whatever that is. I haven't got a clue...  :-)

Comment: That's what I thought :( Darn licensing kills us. Thanks man.